Book Identification: Gamebook about a kid stuck in a science museum after closing
I remember reading this book as a kid, so it must have been published before 2012. The book is a choose your own adventure style, or a game book where you choose the next step in the story by flipping to a specific page. The book expected you to keep a separate paper to keep track of the items you had throughout the story. But I don’t think the book was choose your own adventure branded.
I don’t remember the book having any illustrations. I don’t remember what the cover looks like. It’s not Space Age Terrors! by Hilary H Milton. The book was published in the US and possibly other English speaking countries.
In the book, a kid gets trapped in a science museum after hours after getting locked in on accident. If I remember correctly, he was left behind after a school field trip. The kid must solve puzzles to escape the museum and the all powerful evil entity that’s controlling the facility and preventing him from leaving (I think it’s a rouge computer or something like that but I don’t remember too well). Among the hazards are:
A maze with a room containing a humming giant magnet. Enter the room after choosing to follow the humming noise and you get stuck to it. If you have braces, you die. If not, you still lose all metal objects on your person, such as any keys you are carrying.
A black snake coiled around a laser pointer. You must throw a stink bomb at it to drive it away and grab the laser pointer for later. The failure option is throwing a flashbang.
A anatomical model of a man with no skin. He blocks the stairwell to a floor you must go to. To solve the puzzle, you must shine the laser pointer you grabbed in his eyes to prevent him from catching you. Since he has no skin, he has no eyelids and is therefore blinded, allowing you to escape. I remember this one so well because it scared the shit out of me as a kid.
I don’t remember the ending or the rest of the puzzles because the book was too scary for me and I never beat the game. All I remember is that after escaping and defeating the villain in a final showdown, for some reason the protagonist gets stuck in a movie set for a Tarzan-esque movie. Very much a here we go again ending. If I had to guess maybe that’s the plot to the next book in a series?

Could this be Into the Jaws of Doom by R.L. Stine?

Help! You're trapped in the Hall of Science. And a mad Super Computer wants to keep you there forever.
Escaping is the ultimate challenge. Because in this book, there's only one way out. That's right. Make one mistake -- and you're cake!
The Hall of Science is filled with tools you can use to protect yourself against a terrifying T-rex, a rampaging robot arm, and other enemies. But look out! The giant mutated germ will make you sick. And the pendulum will hypnotize you... to death!




Well done @Valorum - if anyone could answer a gamebook question this fast, it would be you!

@AJM - Stine is after my time, but I was was quite the fan of Peter Jackson.
